# Find a list of substring into a list of strings with python

Tags: python, string, list, find, substring

I have a list of links and want to select some them based on  list of subtrings into the link. I'd like to select the links with the substrings **medalha** or **mencao-honrosa**. Following a sample of selected links.

```
https://onciencias.org/resultado/detalhe/9-ano-ensino-fundamental/medalha-ouro
https://onciencias.org/resultado/detalhe/9-ano-ensino-fundamental/medalha-prata
https://onciencias.org/resultado/detalhe/9-ano-ensino-fundamental/medalha-bronze
https://onciencias.org/resultado/detalhe/9-ano-ensino-fundamental/mencao-honrosa
https://onciencias.org/resultado/detalhe/1-serie/medalha-ouro
https://onciencias.org/resultado/detalhe/1-serie/medalha-prata
https://onciencias.org/resultado/detalhe/1-serie/medalha-bronze
https://onciencias.org/resultado/detalhe/1-serie/mencao-honrosa
https://onciencias.org/resultado/detalhe/2-serie/medalha-ouro
https://onciencias.org/resultado/detalhe/2-serie/medalha-prata
https://onciencias.org/resultado/detalhe/2-serie/medalha-bronze
https://onciencias.org/resultado/detalhe/2-serie/mencao-honrosa
https://onciencias.org/resultado/detalhe/3-serie/medalha-ouro
https://onciencias.org/resultado/detalhe/3-serie/medalha-prata
https://onciencias.org/resultado/detalhe/3-serie/medalha-bronze
https://onciencias.org/resultado/detalhe/3-serie/mencao-honrosa
https://onciencias.org/resultado/detalhe/4-ano-tecnico/medalha-ouro
https://onciencias.org/resultado/detalhe/4-ano-tecnico/medalha-prata
https://onciencias.org/resultado/detalhe/4-ano-tecnico/medalha-bronze
https://onciencias.org/resultado/detalhe/4-ano-tecnico/mencao-honrosa
```

I did the following code and it's working. What's best another way to write this code and avoid to use **or** to separate the substrings.

```
for temp_link in list_links:
    if(str(temp_link).find('medalha') != -1 or str(temp_link).find('mencao-honrosa') != -1):
        links.append(url_home+temp_link[1:])
        print(url_home+temp_link[1:])
```

Thank you.

Comment: Be careful with using `in`, it behaves in a way that can seem surprising. For example, if I'm looking for the word `'cat'`, `'cat' in 'catastrophe'` would return True.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
[url for url in urls if 'medalha' in url or 'mencao-honrosa' in url]
```

or if you have a list of search terms, maybe something like this.

```
search_terms = ['medalha', 'mencao-honrosa']
[url for url in urls if any([term in url for term in search_terms])]
```